# Does Mercurial Strip Extension change commit hashes?

Tags: mercurial, strip, mercurial-extension

I want to delete one changeset from my repo and thinking about using strip extension. Is that extension change commit hashes after I strip polluted changeset?

Comment: What hashes do you expect that it might change? It doesn't strip a change from the middle of a bunch of changesets, it'll strip the changeset and all its descendants. If you need to rebase any descendants to keep them then yes their hashes will change because their parents have changed.

Comment: I was worried, if it change commit hash (as it removes some changesets in middle) after I executed strip which in tern will affect if the repo is used as sub repo. Anyways, I will try some examples..

Comment: Yeah, if you want to strip something out in the middle of a series of commits then the commits that were based on the stripped one will change hashes, and if you've got other repos using it as a subrepo and referencing any of those commits then they won't be able to find the commits. Does it need to be stripped, could you just back out the changes? https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout